# IE8 Css background-position:right is not working fine, as it shows an extra line to right, have nay one faced this issue before?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, background-position

this happens when i set my background-position to right in IE8 Only...

you can see that in the following URL : http://www.scrapingweb.com/quote.html  (Contact Us tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to reduce the width of the HTML or the body like this

body{width:99.6%}

or

html{width:99.6%}  - preferred

And worked fine

> you can also reduce the width of the
>   parent container for example DIV to
>   width:99.9% and this works too.

*I prefer to make it with css hack to be read only on IE8.*

Comment: I have a div that is 100% wide, I reduced it's size to 98% and it works great... IE always has to be a trouble maker.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify both positions e.g.:

```
background-position: right top
```

If you only specify one keyword, the second value will be "center"

Comment: i did so i gave it right and top but the problem is in the background-position-x as it shows an extra 1px to the right.

Comment: Can you post a link to check it out?

Comment: you can see it here in this page http://www.scrapingweb.com/ please have a look on Contact Us tab in the top navigation. don't forget to use IE8